# Men of the past

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

J.R.R. wrote about the dragon, thinking of these men.
Issur performed and challenged the locals to do a crossing, thinking of these men.
G.R.R. wrote about the killer of the giant, thinking of these men.

Single, splitted in two, first is latin, last is English. Present, not past!

Writing about all this in English is one thing, but doing it in Latin gives more fullness.
The first five figures in Latin, plus a double, is her last name, the first figure of this kind in the Hebrew five is her first name.
She was his lover, together with him at the last wedding of this kind, in the land of these fierceful men!

Who is he?